# How do I print all values associated to duplicate keys?

Tags: python, pandas

It took me a while to realize that my printed dictionary is not outputing all values. My keys are a sum function and my values are unique strings.
e.g.:

```
{(target_test == pred_dict['p0']).sum(): str(alg_dict[0].__name__),
(target_test == pred_dict['p1']).sum(): str(alg_dict[1].__name__),
(target_test == pred_dict['p2']).sum(): str(alg_dict[2].__name__)}
```

If the key sum result matches (duplicate result) - I only get a random (dictionary is not ordereddict) value associated to the same key sum result and I am lost as to how to list **each** name from the values next to the key result (like a delimited list of values for each key).
Like:

```
{10: Alg1, Alg2
  9: Alg3}
```

I would like to know also how to get the values as unique rows, like:

```
Score | Alg
10    | Alg1
10    | Alg2
9     | Alg3
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I currently went the route of giving a choice to the user in selecting his/her algorithm based on seeing the results (made them into a list of lists DataFrame and wove in a selector via index).
Still would like to know how my dict solution could've worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas Index.duplicated() like:

```py
import pandas as pd 

idx = pd.Index([100, 50, 45, 100, 12, 50, None]) 

idx.duplicated(keep = False)
```

Result is:

```
 array([ True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: How can I use this to figure out which score is to which name?
Seems that more steps are necessary.
Plus I will need to differentiate a clear winner from a duplicate key score if there are >1 max scores.